# how to show zero cent in amount in words when there is .00 in decimal value

Tags: vb.net

Public Function AmountInWords(ByVal nAmount As String, Optional ByVal wAmount _
                 As String = vbNullString, Optional ByVal nSet As Object = Nothing) As String
    'Let's make sure entered value is numeric
    If Not IsNumeric(nAmount) Then Return "Please enter numeric values only."

```
Dim tempDecValue As String = String.Empty : If InStr(nAmount, ".") Then _
    tempDecValue = nAmount.Substring(nAmount.IndexOf("."))
nAmount = Replace(nAmount, tempDecValue, String.Empty)

Try
    Dim intAmount As Long = nAmount
    If intAmount > 0 Then
        nSet = IIf((intAmount.ToString.Trim.Length / 3) _
            > (CLng(intAmount.ToString.Trim.Length / 3)), _
          CLng(intAmount.ToString.Trim.Length / 3) + 1, _
            CLng(intAmount.ToString.Trim.Length / 3))
        Dim eAmount As Long = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(intAmount.ToString.Trim, _
          (intAmount.ToString.Trim.Length - ((nSet - 1) * 3)))
        Dim multiplier As Long = 10 ^ (((nSet - 1) * 3))

        Dim Ones() As String = _
        {"", "One", "Two", "Three", _
          "Four", "Five", _
          "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"}
        Dim Teens() As String = {"", _
        "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", _
          "Fourteen", "Fifteen", _
          "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"}
        Dim Tens() As String = {"", "Ten", _
        "Twenty", "Thirty", _
          "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", _
          "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"}
        Dim HMBT() As String = {"", "", _
        "Thousand", "Million", _
          "Billion", "Trillion", _
          "Quadrillion", "Quintillion"}

        intAmount = eAmount

        Dim nHundred As Integer = intAmount \ 100 : intAmount = intAmount Mod 100
        Dim nTen As Integer = intAmount \ 10 : intAmount = intAmount Mod 10
        Dim nOne As Integer = intAmount \ 1

        If nHundred > 0 Then wAmount = wAmount & _
        Ones(nHundred) & " Hundred " 'This is for hundreds                
        If nTen > 0 Then 'This is for tens and teens
            If nTen = 1 And nOne > 0 Then 'This is for teens 
                wAmount = wAmount & Teens(nOne) & " "
            Else 'This is for tens, 10 to 90
                wAmount = wAmount & Tens(nTen) & IIf(nOne > 0, "-", " ")
                If nOne > 0 Then wAmount = wAmount & Ones(nOne) & " "
            End If
        Else 'This is for ones, 1 to 9
            If nOne > 0 Then wAmount = wAmount & Ones(nOne) & " "
        End If
        wAmount = wAmount & HMBT(nSet) & " "
        wAmount = AmountInWords(CStr(CLng(nAmount) - _
          (eAmount * multiplier)).Trim & tempDecValue, wAmount, nSet - 1)
            Else
        If Val(nAmount) = 0 Then nAmount = nAmount & _
        tempDecValue : tempDecValue = String.Empty
        If (Math.Round(Val(nAmount), 2) * 100) > 0 Then wAmount = _
          Trim(AmountInWords(CStr(Math.Round(Val(nAmount), 2) * 100), _
          wAmount.Trim & "  And ", 1)) & " Cents"
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
```

'        MessageBox.Show("Error Encountered: " & ex.Message, _
'          "Convert Numbers To Words", _
'          MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
'        Return "!#ERROR_ENCOUNTERED"
    End Try

```
'Trap null values
If IsNothing(wAmount) = True Then wAmount = String.Empty Else wAmount = _
  IIf(InStr(wAmount.Trim.ToLower, ""), _
  wAmount.Trim, wAmount.Trim & " ")


'Display the result
Return wAmount
```

End Function

this is my code but when i got .00 in decimal place i want that it should print zero cents

Comment: Please format your code correctly and only post relevant portion of the code.

Comment: Your code is doomed to be unreliable as the variable types don't match up. If you use [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) then Visual Studio will point out problems for you and even suggest corrections to the code. Also, there is no point to having multiple statements on one line - it just makes it harder to read and debug the code.

Comment: You forgot to give an attribution to the source of the code: [Convert Numbers to Words Neatly](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/538816/Convert-Numbers-to-Words-Neatly). It is important to do that so that we can see what you have changed and also so that you are not accused of plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

You check if `nAmount > 0`, but you do not check if `nAmount = 0`.

```
If nAmount = 0 then wAnount = "Zero"
```

Because you are looking at dollars and cents - these are two separate numbers concatenated into a single string for human readability purposes. So, instead of trying to write the entire lot in one function, call it twice, once for the dollar part, and then once for the cents part. This gives you the flexibility to provide an answer of "Zero Dollars and Zero Cents". This will also give you more efficient code in the function.

You also don't check if `nAmount < 0`. What do you do then?